# Is there a way in REXX to pick the latest dataset in a group?

Tags: rexx

Is there a way in REXX to pick the latest dataset in a group?  Instead of GDG, some of our datasets have identical first 5 nodes then a date and time node to make unique.  Looking for a way to automatically pick the latest dataset (equivalent to GDG zero).

Answer (score 1):

2 options

- use [outtrap](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ikja300/outtrap.htm) with [ListCat](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.idac100/lcxmp.htm) level
- use the ispf commands [LMDINIT / LMDLIST](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00/lmdinit.htm%23lmdinit) etc. You need to be running under ISPF. You can run ISPF in a background job if you need to

The ISPF LMDINIT / LMDLIST is probably the easier / nicer of the 2 but you do need to be running under ispf.

The Listcat command:

```
ListCat level(prod.files)
```

For  LMDINIT / LMDLIST

```
Address ispexec

'lmdinit LISTID(listId)  level(prod.files)'

'lmdlist LISTID('listId') ...'
```